# how to make object to play an animation where it needs to play in unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I want to animate an object A so that, when it's certain distance from object, B it gets on top of B and does it's animation. I recorded key frames but **animation is always played at initial location** (where it was recorded originally) in other words I want animation to be depended on player's position not worlds position.

> So how can I make a location depended animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an empty **parent** object for the game object you wish to animate and move the **parent** instead then the object will animate relative to the parent